# Python 3.4.2, Using listbox for an inventory

Tags: tkinter, listbox, python-3.4

I am trying to create a system in which items are chosen from a list using listbox, and once an item is pressed, the user is asked if they want to use this. If they press yes, the item is deleted from the list.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to correctly program this so that once an item is picked from the list, then the commands to use the item are run. This is the code, but the first 25 lines can be ignored as they are just used to bring up the GUI asking if the user does or doesn't want to use the item:

```
from tkinter import *
def YNquestion(questionString): #putting the code necessary for the GUI into a function allows it to be called every time the quesiton is asked
    global answer #allows the vaiable to be used anywhere in the program 
    def yes_command(): #called by the GUI to change the variable when the button is clicked
        answer.set('yes') #.set allows this to exit the GUI as it is a gloabal variable
        window.destroy() #closes the GUI window so the program does no become stuck
    def no_command(): #similar to the procedure above but sets the variable to 'no'
        answer.set('no')
        window.destroy()

    window = Tk() #creates GUI window 

    yes_no_label = Label(window, text=questionString) #sets the label text within this GUI specified as 'window', set to the string specified when called so this can be used in multiple ways such as in tic tac toe or setting gender of character
    yes_no_label.grid(row=0, column=1) #sets a place for the label to be displayed on the GUI

    answer=StringVar() #needed when running Tkinter with multiple Tk instances to allow variable to be used outside of program (value cannot be assigned within tkinter). 

    YESbutton = Button(window, text="Yes", fg='green', command = lambda :yes_command()) #sets the button with test and colour deatils, as well as what happens when pressed. 
    YESbutton.grid(row=1, column=0) #sets button location
    NObutton = Button(window, text = 'No', fg = 'red', command= lambda :no_command()) #same as for button above
    NObutton.grid(row=1, column=2)

    window.mainloop() #required to create the GUI which is essentially an infinite loop waiting for changes (button press)


#this is the seciton of code that handles how the inventory system works
inventory = ["Water", "Rabbit Meat"]
def water():
    YNquestion('Water will restore 5 energy. Use it?') #calls GUI which sets variable and asks for label text as arguement
    choice = answer.get()
    if choice == 'yes':
        print('You have restored 5 energy!')
    else:
        YNquestion.quit 

def inventoryCommand():    
    window = Tk()

    listboxInventory = Listbox(window)
    listboxInventory.pack()

    listboxInventory.insert(END, "Choose an item to use this turn!")

    for item in inventory:
        listboxInventory.insert(END, item)

    turn = True
    while turn == True:
        listboxInventory.curselection()


    mainloop()
inventoryCommand()
```

In what I have tried to create so far, I have only tried to program what happens when 'Water' is pressed. 
Thanks for any help!

---

The comments below were incredibly helpful! I have modified the code to make it neater, and the method of using message box works, to an extent:

from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox 
    inventory = ["Water", "Rabbit Meat"]

```
#this is the section of code that handles how the inventory system works        
def delete_item(listboxInventory, event = None):
    answer = messagebox.askquestion("Delete", "Are You Sure?", icon='warning')
    if answer == 'yes': 
        if listboxInventory.curselection() == "Water":
            listboxInventory.delete(listboxInventory.curselection())
            inventory.remove("Water")
            print ("5 Energy has been restored!")
        elif listboxInventory.curselection() == "Rabbit Meat":
            listboxInventory.delete(listboxInventory.curselection())
            inventory.remove("Rabbit Meat")
            print ("3 Health has been restored!")

def inventoryCommand():    
    window = Tk()

    listboxInventory = Listbox(window)
    listboxInventory.pack()
    listboxInventory.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda _: delete_item(listboxInventory))
    listboxInventory.insert(END, "New item")  

    for item in inventory:
        listboxInventory.insert(END, item)

    mainloop()
inventoryCommand()
```

However, the problem I have now is that I cannot figure out how to delete the item from both the list and the listbox. Clearly, the code I have above does not allow for branching using listboxInventory.curselection as the argument. Does this mean it would be best to scrap the base inventory list and just use one specific to listbox? My original idea was that I could have a list and append or remove from it when items were used but I'm no longer sure if that's possible.

I would also like to make this so that the message is specific to the item so the user knows exactly what they are doing. I would then like this to output once the item is used. It is shown above but as the branching statement does not work, I cannot test if it would work in this way.

Sorry for making this so complicated, and I'm really grateful for any help!

Comment: If some of the lines of code aren't necessary to reproduce the problem, please remove them while still making the code reproduce the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to delete this. Its going in forever loop:

```
turn = True
while turn == True:
    listboxInventory.curselection()
```

Then, import messagebox that will be used to ask a confirmation message: `from tkinter import messagebox` .
Now you can make a function that will be called every time a user selects an item:

```
def delete_item(listboxInventory, event = None):
    answer = messagebox.askquestion("Delete", "Are You Sure?", icon='warning')
    if answer == 'yes': 
        listboxInventory.delete(listboxInventory.curselection())
```

And finally, bind it like this:

```
listboxInventory.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda _: delete_item(listboxInventory))
```